# Configure Elastic search authentication at JanusGraph 0.2.1

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, janusgraph

I'm using **JanusGraph 0.2.1** with Cassandra as backend and **Elasticsearch 6.1** (have separate ES cluster and JanusGraph connect to it via http rest). With the [Elasticsearch X-Pack security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.1/security-settings.html), I was able to enable authentication at my Elastic Search end. But I'm not **able to configure the elasticsearch credential at JanusGraph** configuration yaml.

In my **janusgraph-cassandra-es-server.properties file in /var/janusgraph/conf/gremlin-server/** folder I have added the following configuration:

```
index.search.elasticsearch.client-only: true
index.search.elasticsearch.interface: REST_CLIENT
index.search.elasticsearch.ext.shield.user: <username>:<password>
```

I have followed [this link](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/612#issuecomment-342271880) to get the above-specified configuration.

When I start my JanusGraph, I'm getting the following error:

```
enter SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/var/janusgraph-0.2.0-hadoop2/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
0    [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  -
    \,,,/
    (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
95   [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Configuring Gremlin Server from conf/gremlin-server/gremlin-server.yaml
156  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics ConsoleReporter configured with report interval=180000ms
158  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics CsvReporter configured with report interval=180000ms to fileName=/tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
197  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics JmxReporter configured with domain= and agentId=
199  [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.MetricManager  - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
550  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager  - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=ClusterJanusGraphConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
559  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: janusgraph-1675467593-cassandra
623  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager  - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=KeyspaceJanusGraphConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
623  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: janusgraph-1675467593-cassandra
641  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: 10.10.18.47
641  [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - RemoveHost: janusgraph-1675467593-cassandra
898  [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.core.util.ReflectiveConfigOptionLoader  - Loaded and initialized config classes: 13 OK out of 13 attempts in PT0.194S
964  [main] INFO  org.reflections.Reflections  - Reflections took 40 ms to scan 2 urls, producing 0 keys and 0 values
1034 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration  - Generated unique-instance-id=0a021b061-janusgraph-1675467593-5f598b9b4f-jqtz81
1040 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager  - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=ClusterJanusGraphConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
1040 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: janusgraph-1675467593-cassandra
1043 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.ConnectionPoolMBeanManager  - Registering mbean: com.netflix.MonitoredResources:type=ASTYANAX,name=KeyspaceJanusGraphConnectionPool,ServiceType=connectionpool
1043 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: janusgraph-1675467593-cassandra
1050 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - AddHost: 10.10.18.47
1050 [main] INFO  com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.CountingConnectionPoolMonitor  - RemoveHost: janusgraph-1675467593-cassandra
1060 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Configuring index [search]
1381 [main] WARN  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.es.rest.RestElasticSearchClient  - Unable to determine Elasticsearch server version. Default to FIVE.
org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: GET http://janusgraph-1675467593-elasticsearch-client:9200/: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication token for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}}],"type":"security_exception","reason":"missing authentication token for REST request [/]","header":{"WWW-Authenticate":"Basic realm=\"security\" charset=\"UTF-8\""}},"status":401}
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:354)
at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient$1.completed(RestClient.java:343)
at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.completed(BasicFuture.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.responseCompleted(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:177)
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.processResponse(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:436)
at org.apache.http.nio.protocol.HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.inputReady(HttpAsyncRequestExecutor.java:326)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:81)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalIODispatch.onInputReady(InternalIODispatch.java:39)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
1390 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/gremlin-server/janusgraph-cassandra-es-server.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:82)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:70)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.lambda$new$0(DefaultGraphManager.java:57)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:671)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.<init>(DefaultGraphManager.java:55)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:110)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:89)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:110)
at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:354)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

As you can see, **JanusGraph at startup tries to check connectivity to the elastic-search client by checking the cluster health status but since Janusgraph is not able to add authentication header to the ES cluster status request, its getting blocked.**

Please let me know how to fix it. (I'm looking for a solution that doesn't include JanusGraph upgrade)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @akhi1, Any luck with the authentication to ES from Gremlin ?

Comment: @chikku Nah... Looks like Janus 0.2 doesn't have the capability to add auth to ES call. 
Tweaking the janus initialization code might help you  but I don't recommend going through this much trouble. Also I found that auth is not a free functionality in x-pack for ES 6.1, upgrading ES to the latest is the best option.